# When Elizabeth went back to the boat from the future, why didn't she need an oxygen mask?

Tags: plot-explanation, tenet

In *Tenet*, when Elizabeth Debicki was inverted to meet her husband back in time, how come she didn't need a gas mask?

How come she is able to talk normally?

Comment: I'm sure the conversation on the boat took place in normal time, not inverted time. Otherwise you could also ask why her husband didn't need a gas mask.

Comment: well husband was already in the past, so offcourse he is in normal time. But Elizabeth was in reverse, because the other one entered when she jumped from the boat.

Comment: Related: [Is there a missing scene in Tenet or am I missing something?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/110918/1006)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kat continued to travel backwards in time before reverting herself back into forward motion (using the turnstiles on the Tenet command ship) just prior to the Vietnam sequence at the end.